# How do you conduct contrasts (pairwise comparisons) for a lmer() when your IV is continuous?

Tags: mixed-model, lme4-nlme, multiple-comparisons, contrasts, lsmeans

I am using lmer() to run an analysis with one categorical variable with 2 levels (**task**) and one continuous variable (**farFC**). Below is the model:

```
model <- lmer(respTime ~ task*farFC+ (1 | Subject),dt,control=lmerControl(optimizer = "bobyqa"))
```

Here is the output:

[image]

How do I run contrasts for the interaction term? When I use the code below I only get the task comparison at one specific value of **farFC** = 4.42 which I am assuming is the midpoint. But, how do I get the value at different values of **farFC**? Is there a way to change the default midpoint?

```
emm3 = emmeans(p3, specs = pairwise ~ task|farFC)
summary(emm3)
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For an interaction between a factor and a covariate, what we have is different linear trends for each factor level, and accordingly I suggest you consider looking at `emtrends()`, which estimates the different slopes and allows you to compare them.

Otherwise, you can specify different values to use by adding an `at` argument, e.g., `at = list(farFC = c(2,4,6))`.

I also suggest taking a look at the vignettes that come with the package. There are several, with numerous examples. The [Basics vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/emmeans/vignettes/basics.html) describes what the default value is for a covariate (it is not the midpoint) and the use of `at`. The [Interactions vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/emmeans/vignettes/interactions.html) has discussions and examples of several approaches with interactions. There is even an [index](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/emmeans/vignettes/vignette-topics.html) of vignette topics.